# Unable to find control in detailsview template field

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, detailsview

I have encountered this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when i trying to set a value which i had session from the previous page and set it on a template field. when I debugged it, the session value was there(successfully session over). what i am trying to do is to display the value of what I had session on detailsview.

aspx :

```
 <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False">

    <Fields>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Order Number " SortExpression="poNum">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="test" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("poNum") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>

       </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
```

code behind :

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    ((Label)DetailsView1.FindControl("test")).Text = Session["poNum"].ToString();
   }
```

I was wondering why I was unable to get the control from detailsview??

**EDIT**

```
    Label aaa = new Label();
    aaa.Text = Session["poNum"].ToString();

    Label orderNum = (Label)DetailsView1.FindControl("test"); // orderNum was null here 
    orderNum.Text = aaa.Text;
```

Comment: Well your code-behind has a *lot* of dereferencing in a single statement. I suggest you split it up using local variables.

Comment: Hi, I had edited the codes as what u recommend, but they are still unable to find the control "test".

Comment: Right - but at least you know *which bit is causing the problem* now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the Label in DataBound event of DetailsView.

Comment: but, i want to set the session value to detailsview when the page is loading. I had tried this before, but the code did not run the databound event.

Comment: It is fundamentally? Why don't you just bind session value to DetailsView?

Comment: Yes, i know where the problems lies now. The error would occur because I did not bind it ? After I tried to bind the Detailsview to an objectdatesource, the error was solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling FindControl before data binding the DetailsView? If so, it will return null - nothing there to find yet.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I did not bind anything to detailsview.